# Run/invoke windows batch script from sh or bash script

Tags: bash, batch-file, cmd, msysgit

I have a sh/bash script that needs to call a batch file with parameters (parameters are file names and are given in DOS/Windows format).

Basically I have:
**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
declare var1=$1
declare var2=$2
dosomething var1 var2
...
<invoke batch script> var1 var2
...
dosomethingelse
```

I'm using `GNU bash, version 3.1.0(3)-release (i686-pc-msys)` as the shell, on `msysgit`

The problem is that when i run from script:
`$COMSPEC /c batchfile param1 param2`
either I get an "empty prompt" which looks like bash, but no command result is displayed on the console, either `cmd.exe` start, but doesn't execute the script.

I've tried quoting the params to bash like this:

```
$COMSPEC /c \"batchfile param1 param2\"
$COMSPEC /c \"\"batchfile param1 param2\"\"
$COMSPEC /c \"\"batchfile \"param1\" \"param2\"\"\"
```

But I didn't get any result.

Comment: Are u calling windows batch script from Unix script or vice versa? I was able to call a batch script from shell script with

Comment: i'm calling windows batch from bash

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that I needed to escape the space from the cmd param:

```
$COMSPEC \/c batch-file\ \"$var1\"\ \"$var2\"
```

or

```
$COMSPEC /c batch-file\ \"$var1\"\ \"$var2\"
```

I'm not sure whether the / from /c needs to be escaped, but it works fine both ways escaped.

Comment: Thank you for documenting!  I had trouble even with finding the /c option, I didn't even need arguments, only know how to start the script from within bash. Thanks!